# Converting an int variable to a float

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion

So I have a homework thing that asks me "How do you convert an int to a float?".

Google searches gives me alot of different results, the most promising being Type Casting. 
But what I'm unsure of is how I make the **variable** itself a float from an int.

I.e, i have `int n=5` , and want to later convert it so that it is treated as a float until the code specifies otherwise. How can I do that? 
Can i just do: `n = (float)n`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm  or http://www.improgrammer.net/type-casting-c-language/ . Simple google search

Comment: Cannot change the type of a variable declaration.  I.E. `int a` will always have `a` be an `int`,   However, can convert across an assignment:  `int a=5; float b;  b=a;`   then `b` will contain `5.0f`

Comment: You can't treat `n` as a float by casting. You will have to use a real float and assign the integer to it. There is generally no need to cast when you do: `myfloat = n;`. Now you can use `myfloat` where you need to. Note that changing `myfloat` does not change `n`,  so at some time, you will have to convert back: `n = (int)myfloat;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert int type var to float type val by type casting and also float to int. it is the best way to convert data type.

for int to float =>

```
int a = 6;
float b = (float)a;
```

and for float to int =>

```
float a = 6.0;
int b = (int)a;
```

Answer (score 1):

u can use type casting

```
int x=11;
float = (float)x;
```